# Basic Regression Neural Network unable to learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, regression

- I am trying to train a basic neural network for regression on a dataset to predict the price range of a car. The linear regression model doesn't perform very well for the dataset, thus making a neural network model.
  Here are the layers I used.

  ```
      tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

      nmodel = Sequential()
      nmodel.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=[28,]))
      nmodel.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1))
  ```
- After compiled ,following output can get

  ```
      opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.2)
      nmodel.compile(loss='mean_squared_error' , optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
  ```
- And this is the final function I used to fit it.

  ```
      keras_history = nmodel.fit(X_train, Y_train , batch_size=32 ,epochs=100 , validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
  ```
- The loss for the training set starts to stagnate after 5 epochs usually and the model stops learning after that. The accuracy for the model is also very low, i.e.~=0.0015.
- I have tried a couple of ways to resolve this. I initially thought that maybe the learning rate was too small but when I increased the learning rate, it would not learn either.
- I thought of removing the activation function as maybe the **relu** was causing the neurons to die after it reached a certain loss. That too had no results.
- I have tested out different numbers of layers and different numbers of neurons. In the end, all of them end up having no effect on the model learning.
- I used to make classification neural networks and this is my first time making a regression neural network. I feel like I am missing something quite basic.

Comment: Code must be in the question itself as text, not as external links.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Sorry. I will make sure to have the code in the question from now on.

Comment: Accuracy is not a correct metric here, it is used for classification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look into your notebook and I noted 2 things:

**You shouldn't fit_transform the test set**

We use fit_transform() on the train data to learn the parameters of the scaling on the train data and scale the latter at the same time. However, we only use transform() on test data because we need to keep the scaling parameters learn from the train data in order to scale the test data.
You need to have
`X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)`

**Also, you don't need to scale the target value.**

You can use this instead :

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesnt seem to be helping out either. There is probably some problem with the model rather than the data as the sklearn linear regression model seems to be working for the given data.

Comment: Accuracy can't be used for regression. And for your LinearRegression model you are using `the score()` function which returns the coefficient of determination R² of the prediction. If you want to compare the neural network with the LinearRegression you should compute the MSE of the latter : `lin_mse = mean_squared_error(actual_price, predicted_price)`. Or you can compute the coefficient of determination R² of your neural network.